# HTTPS is not working in Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) for red hat 6

Tags: apache, ssl, tomcat7, redhat, virtualhost

My Apache httpd is installed in `root/apps` folder (all the configuration files of Apache are existing in the directory of `root/apps/apache`) folder.

I am using Tomcat 7 with Apache. Recently i need to support https in Apache http server. For this i have created self ssl certificate as `ca.crt` and keep it in the directory of `/apps/keystore/ca.crt` and also created private key as `ca.key` and keep it in the directory of `/apps/keystore/ca.key`.

After creating these two files i have configured the httpd - `ssl.conf` file which is located in the direcotry of (`/apps/apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf`).

- In this file i have added **SSLCertificateFile "/apps/keystore/ca.crt"** , **SSLCertificateKeyFile "/apps/keystore/ca.key"** , **ServerName example.com:443** and **SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2** under **<VirtualHost *default*:443,>** tag and save this file.
- The listen port in the file is **Listen 443**.

I have also configured `\apps\apache\conf\httpd.conf` file.

- In this file i have set **Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf** in the bottom of the page.
- I also enable `mod_ssl.so` file by putting **LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so** in this file and save it .

After restarting my apache i put the URL of "**[https://example.com/example_folder/**"](https://example.com/example_folder/**%22) on the browser and there is showing that "This page can’t be displayed" but if i use "**[http://example.com/example_folder/**"](http://example.com/example_folder/**%22) then there doesn't showing any problem and getting desirable page.

Please someone help by mentioning what i miss in here and what i will need to do. Sorry for grammatical mistake. Please help

Comment: Your two urls are the same, could you clarify this?

Comment: Hi @Ynjxsjmh , I need to support HTTP and HTTPS for the same URLs so my both URLs are same and one with http and the other with https. Am I doing anything wrong?Thanks for you reply.